# Taking input from inside handlebar template file (.hbs)

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

How to take user input from a handlebar template .hbs file and send it to some other js function as argument

I have tried so far:

```
{{ # each content }}
  <tr role="row">
.....
    <td
      <input name = "a" type="text" id="a_id" />
    </td>
    <td> 
      <button onclick="my_fn(a)"> SUBMIT </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
{{/each}}
```

For each data content there a row is created by this template .hbs file, in each row there is a field for taking user input and after entering text input a `SUBMIT` button is there in each row,clicking which a js function is called. the user input sent to the function `"my_fn"` as argument.

Comment: @ Sandeep Nayak  yes I have edited.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve